# Abstract class with optional parameters to concrete definitions in Scala

Tags: scala, abstract-class, factory

I really like Scala's abstract factory pattern but I'm having difficulty making it work for my use case. I have 'n' number of optional parameters I want to use to create a generic class that can be pumped through my factory to identify a concrete type. Here's an example of the type of traits and models I'm working with:

```
trait Animal {
     def id: Long
}
trait Pet {
     def name: String
}
trait Pest {
     def hasDisease: Boolean
}
```

And then an example case class would be:

```
case class Dog(id: Long, name: String) extends Animal with Pet
case class Cat(id: Long, name: String) extends Animal with Pet
case class Rat(id: Long, hasDisease: Boolean) extends Animal with Pest
case class Cow(id: Long) extends Animal
```

and then the factory would look like this:

```
object Animal {
  def apply(id: Long, name: String) = name match {
    case "Lassie" => Dog(id, name)
    case "Garfield" => Cat(id, name)
  }
  def apply(id: Long, hasDisease: Boolean) = Rat(id, hasDisease)
  def apply(id: Long) = Cow(id)
```

So in the REPL this works great, I can do:

```
Animal(id=2, name="Lassie")
res5: Dog = Dog(2,"Lassie")
Animal(id=1)
res6: Cow = Cow(1)
```

But in my resource, because the parameters are optional (name, hasDisease), I need to be able to construct my abstract animal object like this:

```
Animal(id=1, name=None, hasDisease=None)
res7: Cow = Cow(1)
```

Any idea of how to make this work?

**EDIT**

I'm not necessarily committed to this pattern, but this is just my first attempt. The overall object is I have 'n' number of optional query params and based on which ones are present, I want to map to a concrete representation

**EDIT 2**
As SergGr pointed out, one possibility could be to case match on the presence of parameters

```
object Animal {
  def apply(id: Long, nameOpt: Option[String] = None, hasDiseaseOpt: Option[Boolean] = None) = (nameOpt, hasDiseaseOpt) match {
    case (Some(_), Some(_)) => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Animal can't have both name and disease")
    case (None, Some(hasDisease)) => Rat(id, hasDisease)
    // different approaches to match values
    case (Some("Lassie"), None) => Dog(id, "Lassie") 
    case (Some(name), None) if "Garfield".equals(name)  => Cat(id, name) 
    case (Some(name), None) => throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Unknown car or dog name '$name'")
    case (None, None) => Cow(id)
  }
}
```

This would work great if we had only two other optional parameters, but there is potential we could add another optional param which would make handling this logic a bit tricky

Comment: And what is the expected result if someone has passed an impossible parameters combination such as `Animal(id=2, name="Lassie", hasDisease = true)`?

Comment: ideally i'd like to catch and throw an error similar to if they attempt to get a Dog object without passing in a name

Comment: prolux, I'm not sure about your last comment: if there is no name, how do you know, that the `Dog` was the intended type rather than `Cow`?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to abstract my actual code, but this use case is pretty silly. In my actual code I switch on id. So if you try to just pass id=2 but 2 requires the string param name, then that would error out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm still not sure that I understand your question correctly. First of all, the typical way to represent something optional in Scala is [`scala.util.Option`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/Option.html).

I don't know a simple way to make such code compile-time safe and still usable. With runtime errors depending on your actual goal I see two approaches:

1. You match output type by which parameters are actually present

```scala
object Animal {
  def apply(id: Long, nameOpt: Option[String] = None, hasDiseaseOpt: Option[Boolean] = None) = (nameOpt, hasDiseaseOpt) match {
    case (Some(_), Some(_)) => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Animal can't have both name and disease")
    case (None, Some(hasDisease)) => Rat(id, hasDisease)
    // different approaches to match values
    case (Some("Lassie"), None) => Dog(id, "Lassie") 
    case (Some(name), None) if "Garfield".equals(name)  => Cat(id, name) 
    case (Some(name), None) => throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Unknown car or dog name '$name'")
    case (None, None) => Cow(id)
  }
}
```

2. You match output type by `id` as you suggested in your comment

```scala
object Animal {
  def apply(id: Long, nameOpt: Option[String] = None, hasDiseaseOpt: Option[Boolean] = None) = (id, nameOpt, hasDiseaseOpt) match {
    case (1, None, None) => Cow(id)
    case (2, Some(name), None) => Dog(id, name)
    case (3, Some(name), None) => Cat(id, name)
    case (4, None, Some(hasDisease)) => Rat(id, hasDisease)
    case (id, _, _) if id >= 5 => throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Unknown id = $id")
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Unepxected combination of parameters: id = $id, name = $nameOpt, hasDisease = $hasDiseaseOpt")
  }
}
```

In both cases you may add helper non-optional methods such as

```
  // note that String might be null so it makes sense to use Option(name) rather than Some(name)
  def apply(id: Long, name: String) = apply(id, nameOpt = Option(name))
  def apply(id: Long, hasDisease: Boolean) = apply(id, hasDiseaseOpt = Some(hasDisease))
```

P.S. I suspect that both solutions might be not what you really want. In that case you should describe your real question better.

Comment: Sorry, for the poor explanation. The first method you suggested would be great if we were limited to only two other optional parameters. There is a potential of more being added which would make managing that logic a bit painful. Method 2 is actually a possibility since we have 100+ defined ids but only a select few with specific params. The helper non-optional method is very helpful. Thank you!